# String .format() only returns first character

Tags: python, string, format

I have a small problem with string formatting. I want to substitute {} for answers. When I change answers, Thing will correctly store the new_answer but incorrectly print it. It will somehow only print the first character!

What's going on here? I'm really confused..

```
class Thing(object):

    def __init__(self,sentence,answer=None):
        self.sentence = sentence
        self.blanks = sentence.count("{}")
        self.answer = (answer if answer else "___" for i in range(0,self.blanks))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sentence.format(*self.answer)

    def changeAnswer(self,new_answer):
        self.answer = new_answer

    def returnAnswer(self):
        return self.answer

def test():
    thang = Thing("Please put it in the {}.")
    print thang # Please put it in the ___.
    thang.changeAnswer("BLANK")
    print thang # Please put it in the B.
    print thang.returnAnswer() # BLANK

test()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used a generator when you first initialized `self.answer`, but you used a string in `changeAnswer`. By using argument unpacking, you unpack the generator of strings into individual strings, but you end up unpacking a string into the individual characters.

Something like this should fix it (namely the changes to `changeAnswer`):

```
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, sentence, answer=None):
        self.sentence = sentence
        self.num_blanks = sentence.count("{}")
        self.answer = [answer or "___"] * self.num_blanks

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sentence.format(*self.answer)

    def changeAnswer(self, new_answer):
        self.answer = [new_answer] * self.num_blanks

    def returnAnswer(self):
        return self.answer

def test():
    thang = Thing("Please put it in the {}.")
    print thang # Please put it in the ___.
    thang.changeAnswer("BLANK")
    print thang # Please put it in the B.
    print thang.returnAnswer() # BLANK

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Also, I would avoid methods like `returnAnswer`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks like the real deal. Can you tell a little more about why I should avoid returnAnswer (or send me to a page that can)?

Comment: @user2245942: It's redundant and doesn't really simplify anything. Why would you write `print thang.returnAnswer()` when you can just do `print thang.answer`?